# Please tell me how to write nuxt plugins 'printd'

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js

During development, we implemented the page to print using Printd.

create plugins / printd.ts

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Printd } from "printd";

Vue.use(Printd);
```

The 'plugins' part of nuxt.conifg.ts.

```
plugins: [
... ,
{ src: "~/plugins/printd", ssr: false }]
```

but the error is shown below

```
10:9 No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(plugin: PluginObject<unknown> | PluginFunction<unknown>, options?: unknown): VueConstructor<Vue>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Printd' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject<unknown> | PluginFunction<unknown>'.
      Property 'install' is missing in type 'typeof Printd' but required in type 'PluginObject<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(plugin: PluginObject<any> | PluginFunction<any>, ...options: any[]): VueConstructor<Vue>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Printd' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject<any> | PluginFunction<any>'.
      Property 'install' is missing in type 'typeof Printd' but required in type 'PluginObject<any>'.
     8 | 
     9 | 
  > 10 | Vue.use(Printd);
       |         ^
    11 |
```

help me!!

Comment: plugins/printd.ts
```
import { Printd } from "printd";

const d = new Printd();

export default d;
```

changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding: ***as any*** just like in the following.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Printd } from "printd";

Vue.use(Printd as any);
```

This might be your answer. But if that does not work, try this.

```
import Vue from "vue";
const Printd = require("printd").Printd;

Vue.use(Printd);
```

... And if that still does not work, try this.
file: ~/types/index.d.ts

```
declare module "printd"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
import Vue from "vue"
import { Printd } from "printd";

Vue.prototype.$Printd = new Printd();
```

Then you can access this.$Printd in your whole app.